# What's the meaning for '*' when using netstat command to check result?

Tags: unix, netstat

What's the mean for `*` when using `netstat` command to check result?

```
udp        0      0 10.224.54.76:18253          10.224.2.253:*              ESTABLISHED 30433/wbx
```

I noticed that there are two results, if there need to create two connections for udp?

```
udp        0      0 10.224.54.76:18252          10.224.2.253:37008          ESTABLISHED 30433/wbx     
udp        0      0 10.224.54.76:18253          10.224.2.253:*              ESTABLISHED 30433/wbx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is a wildcard that means `anything`. So that socket is bound to the local address 10.224.54.76, local port 18253, remote address 10.224.2.253, and will accept packets from any remote port.

In your updated question, the first socket will only receive packets from remote port 37008 to local port 18252. The second socket will receive packets from any remote port to local port 18253.

Both of these come from calling `connect()` on a UDP socket. In the first case, port 37008 was specified in the remote address, in the second case port 0 was specified, which means any port.

Comment: update the question, I notice there are two connections, if there exist need to create two? ,if one is for sent, the other is for received?

Comment: I don't know what the added line has to do with the question, since it doesn't have `*`, but I updated my answer.